# Display JSON data in UITableView with swift 4 and Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swift4

I'm new in Swift and i want your help please. I am doing an app parsing JSON data in swift like this:
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0lC5.jpg)
And here is the code that I have write

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var albumArray = [AnyObject]()
    var url = ("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

                  Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
                if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
//
                    if let resData = swiftyJsonVar[].arrayObject {
                        self.albumArray = resData as [AnyObject]; ()

                    }
                    if self.albumArray.count > 0 {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return albumArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CostumTableViewCell

        let title = albumArray[indexPath.row]
        cell?.titleLabel?.text = title["title"] as? String

        return cell!
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The problem is that doesnt't have any error but does not display the data. Also you can see the JSON : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

Comment: Can you explain the "doesn't work" part of the question more precisely?

Comment: @KeyurTailor does not display the data. Sorry

Comment: Have you tried to print the data in console?

Comment: @KeyurTailor yes , the data in console are printed successfully

Comment: Then I would suggest you to check the format of data that you're receiving.

Comment: did you set `dataSource` and  `delegate` of `tableView`?

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your same code works for me. reload in main queue and make sure u set constraints for the label in the cell. Connect your tableview's data source and delegate and then check.